# Create New Categorical Variable with High, Mid and Low levels based on SD and mean

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
Country Continent  Year lifeExp pop gdp
A       D          1952 1       7   13
A       D          1962 4       10  16
B       D          1952 2       8   14
B       F          1962 5       11  17
C       F          1952 3       9   15 
C       F          1962 6       12  18
```

I would like to create a new categorical variable ‘life.cat’ that denotes for each country in each year, whether it is ‘High’ (> = 1 SD above the mean); ‘Low’ ( < = 1 SD below the mean); or else ‘Mid’, based on its lifeExp compared to that of other countries in its continent in each year.

So far, I am not sure how to include the SD in the computation.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Country, Year) %>% 
    # // or it can be 'Continent', 'Year'
    # group_by(Continent, Year) %>%
    mutate(Mean = mean(lifeExp), 
           SD = sd(lifeExp),
           life.cat = case_when(Mean > (Mean + SD) ~ 'High',     
                                Mean < (Mean - SD) ~ 'Low', 
          TRUE ~ 'Mid'  ), Mean = NULL, SD = NULL) %>%
    ungroup
```

Comment: I think the TO wants to group by Year and Continent, not country, since the task is to check if a country is lower/higher compared to other countries from the same continent.

Comment: @deschen In the OP' post, I read as `for each country in each year`

Comment: but in the last sentence it's clearly stated that: " based on its lifeExp compared to that of other countries in its continent in each year."

Comment: Thank you! I grouped it by continent and year and used the exact same code. However, all the values of life.cat came out as "mid" which is not possible. Is there any way I can solve this?